# Solving the differential equation $\frac{y'}{x\sqrt{1+y'^2}}=C$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have tried solving the differential equation:

$$\frac{y'}{x\sqrt{1+y'^2}}=C,$$

where $y=y(x),\;y'=dy/dx$ and $C$ is a constant. The solution should be a circle apparently. My boundary conditions are $y(1)=0,\;y(2)=1$. Here is my attempt (UPDATE I added LaTex and corrected my solution by using Prajakta's hint):

$$\frac{y'}{x\sqrt{1+y'^2}}=C$$

$$\frac{y'^2}{1+y'^2}=Dx^2$$

$$y'^2(1-Dx^2)=Dx^2$$

$$y'^2=\frac{Dx^2}{1-Dx^2}$$
$$y'=\pm\frac{\sqrt{D}x}{1-Dx^2}$$

$$\int \;dy=\pm\int \frac{\sqrt{D}x}{1-Dx^2}\;dx$$

$$u=1-Dx^2,\;\;du/dx=-2Dx,\;\rightarrow\;-\frac{1}{2D}\;du=x\;dx$$

$$y=\pm\int \frac{\sqrt{D}x}{1-Dx^2}\;dx=\pm\frac{\sqrt{D}}{2D}\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{u}}=\pm\frac{\sqrt{D}}{2D}\left(2\sqrt{u}+H\right)$$

$$y=\pm \frac{\sqrt{D}}{D}\left(\sqrt{1-Dx^2}+H\right)$$

$$y=\pm \frac{\sqrt{D}}{D}\left(\sqrt{D\left(\frac{1}{D}-x^2\right)}+H\right)$$

$$y=\pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{D}-x^2}+N$$

Thank you =)

Comment: What do the initial conditions change the constants to?

Comment: I didn't check that yet. I thought my solution is not correct because according to my problem set the answer should be circle and I got an ellipse if I'm not mistaken?...do you think my solution is correct until where I have finished?

Comment: Why not put all the steps in Latex?

Comment: Roger that @Narasimham, I will change them. I got lazy, because I already had my solution as an image, but I didn't have the Latex anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In second last step, you have left an erroneous $2$ hanging around in denominator.
$$ 2F = 2EC= \frac{-2C}{2D} = \frac{-2C}{2C^2} = -\frac{1}{C}$$
This will solve the problem, by removing the factor of $\frac{1}{4}$ as coefficient of $x$.

Comment: Thank you, noticed it immediately and corrected =)

Answer (score 1):

Since $ D = C^2 $ ,  letting $ C x  = u $ we have

$$ \int  C dy  =   \pm \int \dfrac {u du }{{\sqrt{1 -  u ^2}   } } + G  $$

and rest all OK.

Comment: Thank you! =) Appreciate it